# Click a button whose XPATH is never the same (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button, xpath, random

Im trying to use python to click a button from a react page, but it generates like a token everytime the page is reloaded and I cant figure out how to put this to work
This is the button:

```
<button class="mantine-UnstyledButton-root mantine-Button-root mantine-ap0q7a" type="submit" data-button="true">
   <div class="mantine-1wpc1xj mantine-Button-inner">
      <span class="mantine-1ryt1ht mantine-Button-label">Click to login</span></div></button>
```

Edit: That **"mantine-1ryt1ht"** part is the one that messes it up. Mantine is always the same, but the following part is the one that changes everytime the page loads.

I tried using this, but it didnt work:

```
for button in WebDriverWait(chrome, 1200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Click to login']"))):
  button.click()
```

This is the only thing that is missing for me to finish my project, and I didnt want to use like pyautogui because I want it to run minimized.

Please save me from this lack of knowledge loop.

Comment: You probably want filters on parent elements to get just one result, narrow down the area of the website to search. Maybe search for `type="submit"` since it is static.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a button element which will be a constant on each page so if we use a loop like this:

```
def find&click():
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button') #this will get all the buttons on the page
for button in buttons: #this will iterate through all the buttons 
    if button.text == "Click to login" #this will find the one called "Click to login"
        button.click() #this clicks the button

find&click()
```

so this program looks for all the html tag for the button which is "<button  /button*>
.Once they are found it will go through each one looking at the text of each until it finds the one with the text "click to login".
Once found it will click the button.
This will not rely on any class names,ids or xpath and it will never change.

This should now always find the button on the page and click it. Let me know if you need anything else happy codeing :)

Comment: This worked partially, but due to my lack of information about my issue.
It does what you said if I do it in a button that is already visible and in the screen, but the part I missed is that the button is not always visible, it appear after 15 minutes.
I tried to put it into a wait.ultil loop but its not waiting until...
I can update the code here in around 10 hours when Im back from work so you can check what im doing wrong

Comment: No worries let me  know when you have your code updated and we can take a look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

`button[text()` will not work because there is no direct text()-node with that string.
You can try the following XPath's:

A. use a explicit path to the text()-node

```
//button[div/span/text()='Click to login']
```

or

B. use `normalize-space(.)` where the the `.` are the combined text()-nodes and normalize-space will get rid of optional white space characters.

```
//button[normalize-space(.)='Click to login']
```

or

C. use contains on the combined text()-nodes.

```
//button[contains(.,'Click to login')]
```

Comment: I couldnt put it to work, maybe im overly dumb hahah. But today after work ill try it with more patience. Thanks!